# Ternary Operator in jQuery statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement, ternary-operator

I'm new to Javascript, CSS, HTML, and jQuery, and came across this line of code that uses the `condition ? if true : if false` statement, and I'm trying to understand it. What would it's equivalent `if() {} else {}` statement look like? This is the line of code:

```
$('.app-container').css('background', this.background ? `url(${this.background.get('Href')})` : `url(${DefaultImage.Background}`);
```

Thanks for any explanation :)

Comment: Not sure what's with all the extra single code-quotes in your example though :)

Comment: I can only guess that the backticks indicate [ES6 template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), or else they're part of some other unknown JS framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to expand the second parameter that was passed to `url()` to an `if`, `else` as that is evaluated first:

```
if (this.background)
    bgurl = `url(${this.background.get('Href')})`
else 
    bgurl = `url(${DefaultImage.Background})`

$('.app-container').css('background', bgurl);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for exactly what this would look like with a traditional `if-else`:

```
if (this.background)
    $('.app-container').css('background', `url(${this.background.get('Href')})`);
else
    $('.app-container').css('background',`url(${DefaultImage.Background}`);
```

In javascript the ternary operator follows this basic premise:

`(condition) ? (what will happen if condition evaluates to true) : (what will happen if condition evaluates to false)`

Sometimes they can be difficult to decipher but in the right situation (like this one) they can save you from writing 'extra' code.